# Download multiple files with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, prawn

I'm currently using PRAWN with latest release of rails and I can't figure out how to download multiple files with a single HTTP request. in my controller I have the following code:

```
Fill PDF with my stuffs...
PDF.render_file "foo.pdf"
send_file("foo.pdf")
```

And it download correctly the file but - if after that - I put another istance of the same code...it will execute only the last one, foo2

```
PDF.render_file "foo.pdf"
send_file("foo.pdf")
PDF.render_file "foo.pdf"
send_file("foo2.pdf")
```

Moreover, If at end...I wish to render another view, I can't do it.

Question is:

How can I download 2 different files in a single action inside controller and, finally, render a view?

Comment: You can only retrieve one file per request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cant unless you zip them and then send back the zip file

Comment: Are you sure? Can I, at least, download a file and render a view?

Comment: You can render the view first and then use javascript window.location.href to browse to the file url, kinda of that file sharing sites like rapidsahre do with the counter thing.

Answer (score 1):

You could use pdftk to combine the pdf's on the server, and send ONE pdf.

Other than that,  to only way to get multiple file downloads is to have the broswer send multiple AJAX requests to the server,  and each one end with send_file.

That would take some JavaScript,  and you'd end up with multiple file download dialogs popping up on your screen.